# Pick up the environment specific properties file at run time

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to pick up the environment specific properties file at run time from class path

I am still learning Spring Boot,
we can do it using environment variables or vm arguments or put in application.properties in maven run configuration

However we will always have to change the code at the time of deployment for a specific env if we put it application.properties.

I want to pick it up at run time without modifying the code at all.

Comment: add `SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILES=dev` as environment variable

Comment: yeah definitely, i don't want to change it every time i deploy to different environments.

Comment: In different environments you will set it diff value right?

Answer (score 4):

Use spring profiles. Create application.properties for each profile like below:

```
application-dev.properties
application-prod.properties
```

Keep the `application.properties` as the master copy. If a property is missing in the profile-specific file then it will be picked from the master `application.properties` file as a fallback.

Then either set the following in `application.properties` or set as an `environment variable` or as a `system property` to activate a `profile`:

**In application.properties:**

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

**Environment variable:**

```
export spring_profiles_active=dev
```

**System Property:**

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev xyzapp.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try System.setProperty() to set something at application level. But if you don't reset it will remain throughout application.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: System.getProperty(key) will be used in java to fetch something set at application level and System.SetProperty(key,value) will be used in java to set something in application. Here key is the property u want to fetch or update.